# Windows 10 Action Center completely Missing

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center

I recently installed Windows 10 Enterprise activated it and updated it.

I find it really annoying because I got no Action Center (or Notification Center) at all. I have seen lots of videos there is a small notification or bubble like icon that shows the action center. As for me it is completely missing and the notifications shows up above task bar. No icon no anything.

I have done nothing to disable it.

I have done some windows 10 tweaks like 
deleting all Metro apps using these commands in power shell

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage

and disabled lockscreen, windows defender , OneDrive and configured Windows Updates to notify before download and install using gpedit.msc

I am sure I had no Action Center or the icon even before this tweaks. So what is going on with my Action Center and my Windows is working fine expect this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might be it is disabled, Try below method.

Go to Local Group Policy Editor. If you cant make that out than go to run and write this command - gpedit.msc to open local group policy editor.

In the left pane - -> User Configuration - -> Administrative Template  -- > Start Menu and Taskbar - -> in the side panel find - "Remove Notification and Action Center". - -> Double Click on that - -> if it is enabled then make it disabled. Restart your PC.

Might you get the solution.

Source taken from : http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6004-action-center-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html

OR

you can do something like this :

Start Menu - - > Setting - -> System - -> Notification and actions - -> Turn system icon on or off. - ->  Action Center - -> if it is off - -> On it.

Comment: Oh My God I feel real stupid. Been searching for hours in Google everything good in group policy editor and registry. Seems like it was disabled in System Icons simply enabled it and the icon is back and its working. Thanks so much for solution even Google could not have given me this answer :)

Comment: On my system settings I don't have that option. And in Policy Editor it shows as "Not configured" with a comment "NO". Tried changing it to "Enabled" - no dice...

Answer (score 0):

@bijay135 @BrotskyTv @weir @Gediminas Jeremiah Gudelis:

Looked at my Windows 10: 
System Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

**'Turn system icons on or off'** switch is actually located at:

1. System `(WinKey + i)`
2. Personalisation
3. Taskbar (last in the left-sided list)
4. Scroll down to '**Notification area**'

Cheers.

Comment: Am on Win11, there's no "notification area" at all, and no "system icons" option anywhere to be found :-\